# Trouble with If/Else Statements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, button

I am working on a basic pager system for my dad's dental office. Essentially I am recreating this device, but in a much prettier touch screen form using Kindles. Basically, the buttons have 3 state: Off, On, Flashing. SO the idea is that I want to host a JavaScript back end that all of the Kindles are set on. They can all send and receive updates. I'm having a surprising amount of issues a creating a button that goes through these three states.

I created a basic counter that displays in a button like this.

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var state = 0;
function onClick() {
    state += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = state;
};
</script>
<button type="button" onClick="onClick()">Click me</button>
<p>State : <a id="clicks">0</a></p>

</body></html>
```

But I am trying to build a function that will tell the style to loop from the 3rd state back to the first, and I didn't imagine I would have this much trouble.  So I tested a few variations of if/else conditions, using the assumption that that the state variable was actually holding the value as the displayed numbers were increasing. it ended up looking something like this:

```
<script>
var state = 0;
function onClick() {
if (state = 0) {
    state += 1;
} else if (state = 1) {
    state += 1;
} else {
state -= 1;
}
```

but this doesn't function... Clearly I don't get how to use conditional statements... in the first example, is the state variable not actually storing the value? What am I doing wrong, is it syntax?

Comment: `=` is not `==`.

Comment: Beyond the mistake of using the wrong syntax, you can use the remainder (`%`) operator to help create a round-robin state value: `state = (state+1)%3`. Thus eliminating the need to make multiple if statements

Comment: Thanks you so much. That is 100x more efficient than what I was doing. I really appreciate you going the extra mile on your reply.

Comment: To be honest though, I don'y understand the math going on there... Do you know a good resource to read about using remainders that way. :)

Comment: Pro-tips for posting: (1) if you know your formatting is bad, don't post it. We have a small set of volunteer editors here who help new users who struggle with the user interface, but we're not impressed with people who create work for us. If good formatting from a phone is hard, then wait until you have desktop/laptop access; (2) do not beg, regardless of how urgent it is. People who answer questions will (and should) answer at their leisure, and they do not need the emotional pressure of pleading to take on more labour than they have comfortable time for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IF-statements, you check for equality using `==` or `===`. A single `=` is used purely for assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Change = to ==
= is for assignment only whereas == is for comaprison purposes